# Changing port for wordpress redirects to old one

Tags: apache, wordpress, ubuntu, port

I am having trouble changing port on Wordpress running locally.

First of all I did run Wordpress on local port 80 (with subfolder: 192.168.0.100/dexy-today). Than I changed port to 1231 in Apache settings (without subfolder: 192.168.0.100:1231).

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.0.100:1231>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/dexy-today
</virtualHost>
```

Settings in Apache are fine, because I have another project running on port 1232 and its not redirecting to port 80.

Hope someone could help fix this.

EDIT: Admin section is loading properly with 1231 port, but not frontend.

Answer (score 3):

You have change two configuration values in Database.
go to wp_options table and change value of

> option_id 1
>
> option_name siteurl

and

> option_id 37
>
> option_name home

e.g. if its `localhost/dexy-today` then make it `localhost:1231/dexy-today`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a `Listen 1231` directive in your httpd.conf? You'll need that.

Comment: @Dejan okay, so what exactly happens when you try to access the site? Anything in the error logs?

Comment: It just loads `localhost` main page (With 'It Works etc'). Like WordPress redirect to port 80.

Comment: googling `Ubuntu Apache error log` gives me this - http://fuzzyblog.wordpress.com/2005/12/08/ubuntu-where-is-the-apache-error-log/

Comment: My bad, sorry for not Googling. Its on other computer, so I can not copy, but I found that Apache is loading '/var/www/dexy-today/dexy-today', so that is not valid. Backend is working fine, but frontend like it was remember its old file path...

Comment: @Dejan that might be WP's doing, not sure. Did you follow the instructions in http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress ? You could try rebuilding the permalink structure in WP-admin, maybe some rewrite rules need to be fixed

Comment: No, I didn`t... I am new to WP, so I was hoping for quick solution.

Comment: @Dejan If you're moving from a sub-folder to the main domain, I think the steps described in that document are the minimum. Else your blog won't work

Comment: Ok, thanks for help. I know that I need to read Codex. Think that new thing will be fresh copy of WP.